# Can I manually invoke the same autosizing code that happens when the device rotates?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, autosize

I have a UIViewcontroller with its UIView displaying the statusBar at the top, then below that a UINavigationBar. Below these is a UIImageView with storyboard "autosizing" configured so the UIImageView takes up the remainder of the screen.

When I programmatically hide the statusBar and navBar, the UIView doesn't expand into the space vacated by the statusBar and navBar like the autosizing settings suggest it would. However, if I rotate the device at this point, it does expand properly.

So there appears to be some cascade of resizing/autosizing that happens when the device is rotated. If I could just toggle the nav and status bars then invoke the mysterious "magicalPositionRecalculator" that gets called on resize that would be perfect. Can I do this? Do you know what method sets this in motion? Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the new dimension (`frame` property) of your view in code (`self.view.frame = self.view.superview.bounds` should do). If you only want to adjust the layout without resizing you can call `[self.view setNeedsLayout]`